# Drawing a border in full screen

Tags: android, border

this is my code to draw the rectangle:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape" >

    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="#000000" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />

    <corners android:radius="0dp" />

    <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />

</shape>
```

then it appears like this:

[image]

but that's what i wannt:

[image]

can anyone help me with that?

Comment: there might be a padding in your base activity , remove this

Comment: Simply remove the paddings from the parent

Comment: thanks a lot , it works , thx for your help , thanks for the fast answer :*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove padding from your layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/style"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape" >

    <stroke
        android:width="15dp"
        android:color="#999999" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />

    <corners android:radius="0dp" />

    <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />

</shape>
```